# What should throw new Error() output in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling

I have some code that throws an `Error`. Is this code correct or am I doing something wrong syntactically? Is this the default behavior of `throw new Error()` or am I doing something wrong? Please help me.

```js
function Test1(test: boolean): boolean | never {
    if (test === true)
        return false;

    throw new Error();
}
Test1(false);
```

This produces the following output:

```
/home/midhun/typescriptexamples/typescriptexample.js:79
    throw new Error();
    ^

Error
    at Test1 (/home/midhun/typescriptexamples/typescriptexample.js:79:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/midhun/typescriptexamples/typescriptexample.js:81:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

**My final question:** How to catch this error in TypeScript?

Comment: the code behaves as expected.... your condition says if it is equals true return false... when you call it it is NOT true therefore it continues to the next line which is throw new Error()

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro but this crashes the program right how can i catch the error

Comment: Isnt the above code snippet a bad approach

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro it just crashes the program right?

Comment: this isn't a TypeScript question

Comment: @Aluan Haddad. I didnt get you

Comment: @AluanHaddad how to catch error. this way of coding crashes program right.How can i do it in typescript

Comment: [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: @Krisztian Balla Thanks for editting .Even though this is a silly question

Comment: @somanraj: Well it wasn't when you posted it otherwise you wouldn't have asked it, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript (and therefore in TypeScript) if you want to prevent a `throw`n error from crashing things, you need to `catch` it by using a [`try..catch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch). The code which might lead to an error must be inside the `try` block, and the code which deals with an error should be inside the `catch` block:

```
console.log("Starting up...")
try {
  const ret = Test1(false);
  console.log(ret);
} catch (err) {
  console.log("uh oh, I caught an error", err)
}
console.log("Moving on...");
```

This produces logs like

```
/* [LOG]: "Starting up..." 
[LOG]: "uh oh, I caught an error",  Error: {} 
[LOG]: "Moving on..." */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAFQKYGcoEYAUUNQBciARnHADaoCGYAlMWZTUgD6JioBuqATogG8AsAChEiGMER4CiALwLEUXiFR1R48b1RQQvJMGoV0qANyiNSgBa84Adw6oHAUV63eOOuZEBfCyIgEdGYAOgo4AHMcACIAZShqXlgwCMQQAAcQrOj1EWUAT0FLQLBMRG0oeRQCXENjNW9xEuCqMMicCq9RH0QIaigIK2k+XjoisV6g0PCo6JAhuCsAGkQASV7qEAirStpEEbheaJWR3L8AqdaZmIBZOC4YFMQELJCc71EAegAqRABtAAyAHkAOIAXWIcQSSUeqQyr2iokBoIhiDmC2Waw2Wx2iD2ByOK0QrncxAE52R4MhdweTxe2UQ30+QA)